# TableView Read Data from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

This is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    var postData = [String]()
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        databaseHandle = ref?.child("Posts").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot)in
            let post = snapshot.value as? String

            if let actualPost = post {
               self.postData.append(actualPost)
               self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

}
```

I want my UITable to read any changes I make in my firebase console but with this code nothing shows up on the UITable. When I change it to `DataEventType.childChanged`, it works but it only adds new posts and not changes to previous post. What am I doing wrong? I just want all changes to show on the UITable that I make on Firebase.

Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted is correct. Where's the rest of your VC ? `numberOfRowsInSection` ?

Comment: your output is displayed in tableView or not ?

Comment: `.value` should be picking up any changes made in the database. You can either observe `.value` OR a combination of `.childAdded`, `.childChanged`, `.childRemoved` and `.childMoved`. `.value` keeps track of all of those by itself.

Comment: There are two things that I see potentially incorrect: are you sure `snapshot.value` holds a `String`? Normally it holds `[String, AnyObject]`. Also, `self.tableView.reloadData()` should be called in the main thread, which you aren't doing.